# PDO query utilizing two tables with separate parameters

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have two tables. One with login information `logins` which holds `password` column and one with emails `emails` which holds `email` column and `loginID` column. I would like to use parameters on both tables. I would like to find row in **emails** where email=? and then take the corresponding login id inside that row and match this to a row in **logins** table. I would then like to match the password to the row in **logins**. A double separated *where* statement from *two tables*.

Something along the lines of:

```
$prepareTables=$listersDatabase->prepare("select*from emails where email=? left join logins on emails.loginID=logins.ID where password=?");
$prepareTables->execute(array("email@email.com","password123"));
```

Any help is appriciated

Comment: what's the problem, Your code seems to be correct. Can you tell us a little bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    emails 
INNER JOIN logins 
ON emails.loginID=logins.ID 
WHERE 
    emails.email=?
AND
    password=?
```

I used `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN` as you have this table inside a `WHERE` condition anyway. You must put all your conditions inside one `WHERE` clause.